# Cast SqlDataReader field to a string if the field is not a string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, casting

I need to read from SqlDataReader in C# and I know the field will be of type varchar, char, date, int, double, or string.

What I would really like to do is simply:

```
string str = (string)reader["field"];
```

Obviously I will get a cast exception as you cant cast a date, double, etc to string, I am trying to figure out the simplest way of casting everything coming back from db as a string.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(reader["field"]`) or `"" + reader["field"]` ought to work (for most primitive types), but IIRC, `DBNull` needs to be handled special. Anyway, you're looking to *convert*, not *cast* (although confusingly, some casts really convert..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out the simplest way of casting everything
>   coming back from db as a string.

Just call `ToString` method.

```
string str = reader["field"].ToString();
```

Just make sure that field name exists.

Comment: Can `reader["field"]` ever return null? Or will it return DBNull?

Comment: @user2864740, if "field" doesn't exist, for example you specify 'SomeField` and it doesn't exist in the result you will get back null and an exception.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point. What about if a nullable column has NULL? (I don't play with SqlDataReader much.)

Comment: i think a check for IF(IsDBNull) would be in place before the cast

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = reader["field"].IsNullorDBNll() ? string.Empty : reader["field"].ToString()
```